# Firebase Auth: What does 'read' and 'write' exactly mean in security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm aware of the security rules and how it can be used but confused on the concept.
1) Does 'read' mean that the client user is able to see my database if I share my firebase credentials?
2) Does 'write' mean that the client user is able to overwrite details on my database using the firebase credentials?
3) If I make it read = true for users, are they able to see my entire database with some private information?

Can someone break down exactly what it all means precisely, because i don't think firebase exactly mention what 'read' and 'write' actually is.

Thanks.

Comment: "I don't think firebase exactly mention what 'read' and 'write' actually is" -> In addition to Peter's answer, I would kindly suggest you read the documentation in detail https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security, including all the pages and including watching the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rules:

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Means everyone can access the database, if someone knows the project id then they can execute a `curl -X DELETE` and delete nodes from your database. That's why you dont use `read = true` and `write = true`. The rules are there to secure your app:

```
// These rules don't allow anyone read or write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

This means no user can either read from the database nor write anything to the database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/resolve-insecurities

Comment: So if I were to put read = true and false = true, they able to see my entire database but not make any modifications? Sorry just want to confirm, these are some serious options to consider for a database.

Comment: read = true, they can read from the database. So in your code if you are retrieving data they can see that data in the application. write = false, then they cant send data to the database, so if you have a form and on submit you send data to the database they cant do that since its false

Comment: Sorry will do! Thanks.